# C brace indentation

Tags: indentation, c

I am new to Emacs and trying to learn the basics.

I am writing a few C programs and I noticed that the default brace indentation is as follows:

```c
for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        // code 
    }
```

How would I go about modifying this behaviour to achieve the following instead:

```c
for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [this answer on SO](//stackoverflow.com/a/2542054/2747593), you can do:

```el
(setq c-default-style "bsd")
```

This will set the style for **all** C-based modes. If you want to set it only for one, do e.g.:

```el
(add-to-list 'c-default-style '(c-mode "bsd"))
```

However, setting `c-default-style` will change various other style settings, which may not be what you want. To only change the post-for-loop-brace indentation, do:

```el
(add-to-list 'c-offsets-alist '(substatement-open . 0))
```

(This will shadow the old value, which AFAIK shouldn't cause any problems. See [this question](//stackoverflow.com/q/10063195/2747593) and its answers for possible ways to actually replace the old value.)

---

Now to generalize: how do you find the specific syntactic symbol in the `c-offsets-alist` that you need to modify?

Note the line that has faulty indentation (in this case, the one with the `{` after the `for` loop), and move the point to that line. Then do:

```el
M-x c-show-syntactic-information
```

(or `C-c C-s`). This will give you e.g.:

```
Syntactic analysis: ((substatement-open 16))
```

Another option is to do `M-x c-set-offset` (or `C-c C-o`), which will give you the following prompt:

```el
Syntactic symbol to change: |substatement-open
```

Here the `|` marks the position of the cursor, with the relevant symbol auto-filled for you.

Thanks to [@nispio](//emacs.stackexchange.com/users/93/nispio) for the info!

Comment: To find out which offset you need to modify (e.g. `substatement-open`) you can use the command `c-show-syntactic-information` (bound to `C-c C-s` in c-mode) to find out which offsets are in effect, or `c-set-offset` (bound to `C-c C-o`) to change the offset interactively.

Comment: @nispio Thanks for the info! After experimenting with those two commands, I've edited some additional information into my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the extremely comprehensive and interesting answer Scott.

I tried your suggestions.  I was able to achieve the desired behaviour using (setq c-default-style "bsd") but when I tried (add-to-list 'c-offsets-alist '(substatement-open . 0)), this didn't seem to work.

Comment: In order to automate the majority of this `c-set-offset`-work, you could also use something like this: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20515/setup-c-mode-indentation-braces-and-tabs/20561#20561

Comment: @user12230 Hmm, that's strange. What is the contents of your `c-offsets-alist` after running that command?